# Publishing ASP.NET Site to Azure Changes ClientId in Web.Config

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-web-app-service, adal

I used Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 to create a simple ASP.NET MVC app secured by Azure AD and tested it locally, where everything worked fine.  I then deployed it to an Azure web site, where after authentication the app failed because it said I was using an "invalid client secret".  After much debugging I found that for some reason the ClientId in web.config is getting changed when the app is uploaded to Azure.  I used the SCM tools in Azure to go in and manually edit my web.config file to what I have in my source code and everything works now.

Anyone seen this...is it a known issue anywhere?  I'm working now, but would like to fix it so I don't have to manually tweak the web.config in the future.

Steve

Comment: what happen if you publish to local file system? will your web.config change as deploy to Azure App Service?

Comment: @Steve Peschka: do you put any transformation logic inside web.release.config?

Comment: Hi Xiaomin, the web.config does NOT change if I publish to a local file system.  Kienct89, I don't have any transformation logic inside my debug or release configs.  I just published again to Azure app service though and it put the wrong value in there again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue with this.  The wrong ClientId and ClientSecret was in the publishing profile file, i.e. "My Publishing Profile.pubxml".  I have no idea where it got those values from, because I never provided them.  I have a theory though...I just was changing the application to target .NET 4.61 from 4.52.  I noticed when I ran the publish wizard when targeting 4.52 that the wizard included a box that was checked by default that says "Enable Organizational Authentication".  My best guess is that perhaps with that checked it automatically created a new application definition in Azure AD and used the client ID and secret for it.  Just a guess, trying to explain the unknown.

The fix though was to just change the pubxml file to match what was in web.config and - shazaam - it all worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a transform used during publishing, there is no logic in the Azure deployment that can change your web.config file. So something else must be at play.

I would suggest isolating the repro app to something small and free of sensitive bits such that you can share it on GitHub for further investigation. Also, in the process of doing this, you may be able to identify the root of the problem.